# Can batarang debug angular inside jsp?

Tags: angularjs, batarang

I am new to angularjs and downloaded latest batarang chrome extension.

We have a jsp pages with angularjs in it. Could such application be debugged by batarang ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to know is to try ...

That being said, Batarang seems to be a client side technology, so it should not care about how your HTML was generated. I see no reason for it not to work.

Note that I have no experience with Batarang.